# Nodes vs Enties : consequences on search requests

Tags: nodes, entities, search

I have to store a large amount of content in drupal.

I'm wondering if it's better to split it in different entities to increase performances, or to put all in the node tables (so everything will be in the same tables : books, authors, editors, and so on...)

I'm prefering the entities way, but what about the search performances ?
Is the search API able to check different entities ?
Is the search speed going to really slow down ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Thinking about performance before other considerations is rarely a good idea. There are Drupal sites with content in millions of nodes that perform fine. If you build your own entity type you may well have to replicate or extend existing functionality at the risk of creating new bugs and it won't necessarily mean better performance.

Comment: Thx for your response ;) what do you mean by replicate functionality ? Aren't the mechanisms available for the nodes/bundles also available for the entities/bundles ?

Comment: yes, mostly, and increasingly, with respect to Drupal 8. But there will be dependencies on specific properties and behaviours of node entities relied on by some components.